# How to return the key corresponding to the maximum value in dictionary?

Tags: python

In this code I calculated the average score for each student and return it in a dictionary to create a dictionary with a two-dimensional array:

```
def bestAverage(inputDict):
    dic = {}
    for i in inputDict:
        if i[0] in dic.keys():
            dic[i[0]].append(int(i[1]))
        else:
            dic[i[0]] = [int(i[1])]
    totle_score = 0
    print(dic)
    for key, value, in dic.items():
        for c in value:
         totle_score += int(c)
        Q = len(value)
        avrage = totle_score / Q
        dic[key]= [avrage]
    print(dic)
```

OUTCOME:

```
{'Diane': [35.0], 'Bion': [95.0], 'Jack': [125.0]}
```

NOW, how to return the name with the highest average score?

Answer (score 2):

```
dict = {'Diane': [35.0], 'Bion': [95.0], 'Jack': [125.0]}

highest_scorer = max(dict, key=dict.get)
highest_score = dict[highest_scorer]
```

Reference https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

You can also try `max(iterable)`, but I prefer using `max(iterable, *args)`.

Comment: thank you for your comment, but what I need is the NAME of the person with the highest score and the score itself.

Comment: @sulaimanalomayri isn't that `highest_scorer` and `highest_score`?

Comment: @sulaimanalomayri `highest_scorer` is the NAME of the person with the highest score and `highest_score` is the score.

Comment: @sulaimanalomayri Glad, I could help!. If my solution gives you the desired output, please accept it, Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

```
max_score = max(d.values())[0]
name_max = [k for k,v in d.items() if v[0]==max_score]
```

Comment: I appreciate it, that was correct, can you please write the code outside the print() statement

Comment: i just edited it @AdamSmith. Before edit, there was.

Answer (score -1):

```
import operator
max(dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
```

you can also use

```
max(dic, key=dic.get)
```

Comment: Please explain your logic, and give a little commentary on what your code is intended to do. It can help future readers as well.

Comment: operator is a built-in module providing a set of convenient operators. In two words operator.itemgetter(n) constructs a callable that assumes an iterable object (e.g. list, tuple, set) as input, and fetches the n-th element out of it. Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter